# CakePHP don't include records whose contained model is empty

Tags: cakephp, paginator, containable

So my current paginate settings look like this:

```
    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 30,
        'contain' => array(
                'Model1' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id')
                ),
                'Model2' => array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                                'Model2.type' => 'Sometype'
                        ),
                        'Model3' => array(
                                'fields' => array('someField')
                        )
                )
        )
);
```

What I want to achieve is that when the contained `Model2` happens to be empty (there is no `Model2` with the type `'Sometype'`), then this record of `Model0` (the parent of `Model1` and `Model2`) should not be included in the returned array of `$this->paginate('Model0');`.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that can be achieved with the containable behavior.  I know you can do it with manual joins (disclaimer: I may be off in my query, since I haven't tested it):

```
$results = $this->Model0->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Model2.id <>' => null,
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'model2',
                'alias' => 'Model2',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Model2.type' => 'Sometype',
                    'Model2.model0_id = Model0.id',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'model3',
                'alias' => 'Model3',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Model3.model2_id = Model2.id'
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ));
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the root condition to require a valid id for Model2.

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 30,
    'conditions'=>array(
            'Model2.id >'=>0
    )
    'contain' => array(
            'Model1' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id')
            ),
            'Model2' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                            'Model2.type' => 'Sometype'
                    ),
                    'Model3' => array(
                            'fields' => array('someField')
                    )
            )
    )
);
```

Depending on your model relationships this might not work. It only works for belongsTo and hasOne I believe. In that case, you should start the pagination from Model2 or use bindModel for temporary model relationships.

Answer (score -1):

Set you conditions at the base level of the query rather than inside the contains. Just make sure to prefix them with the model name.

```
public $paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Model2.type' => 'Sometype'
    ),
    'limit' => 30,
    'contain' => array(
        'Model1' => array(
            'fields' => array('id')
         ),
         'Model2' => array(
             'Model3' => array(
                 'fields' => array('someField')
             ),
         ),
    )
```

);